# Cypher: Group by community id

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My database in Neo4j looks like this:

```
(a:ARTICLE)-[:SIMILAR]-(a:ARTICLE)
```

ARTICLES nodes have the community property, it is the id of cluster.

I would like to group articles by community_id, I tried this but nothing happened:

```
MATCH (a:ARTICLE)-[:SIMILAR]-(a:ARTICLE)
WITH a, collect(a.community) as community
RETURN a
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(a:ARTICLE)-[:SIMILAR]-(a:ARTICLE)` incorrectly requires both nodes to be the same (since both use the `a` variable).

In any case, there is no need to even match the relationship.

This should work:

```
MATCH (a:ARTICLE)
RETURN a.community as id, COLLECT(a) AS articles
```